# Передача состояния radiobutton в форму

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго дня, подскажите я получаю состояние радиобаттонов через следующую конструкцию

```
$('input:radio[name=radio]').on('change', function () {
    radioValue = $("input[name='radio']:checked").val();
});
```

Выводя в консоль значение radioValue я получаю правильное изменённое состояние, при передаче его в форму у меня отображается либо состояние которое было при загрузке страницы, либо просто object, каким образом можно передать состояние?

```
(function(w,d,u,b){w['Bitrix24FormObject']=b;w[b] = w[b] || function(){arguments[0].ref=u;
    (w[b].forms=w[b].forms||[]).push(arguments[0])};
    if(w[b]['forms']) return;
    var s=d.createElement('script');s.async=1;s.src=u+'?'+(1*new Date());
    var h=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];h.parentNode.insertBefore(s,h);
})(window,document,'https://bistropechat.bitrix24.ru/bitrix/js/crm/form_loader.js','b24form');


b24form({"id":"5","lang":"ru","sec":"uwp5dl","type":"button","click":"", "presets": {"my_cookie1": "ValueChecked: " + radioValue }});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю была ошибка в формировании объекта для передачи в форму.

```js
var output = $('#output');
var petTypeChoice;
var petTypes = $('input:radio[name="pets"]').on('change', changeHandler);

function changeHandler() {
  petTypeChoice = $(this).val();
}

$('button').on('click', submitHandler);

function submitHandler() {
  output.html(petTypeChoice);
  var formData = {
    id: "5",
    lang: "ru",
    sec: "uwp5dl",
    type: "button",
    click: "",
    presets: {
      my_cookie1: {
        ValueChecked: petTypeChoice
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(formData);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="dogs">Dogs</label>
<input type="radio" name="pets" value="dogs">
<label for="cats">Cats</label>
<input type="radio" name="pets" value="cats">
<label for="hamsters">Hamsters</label>
<input type="radio" name="pets" value="hamsters">

<button>Submit</button>

<div id="output"></div>
```